# benefits of "class" vs "id" tags for a single use html element

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a code academy course and they ask me to use left and right column classes as opposed to id's. I'm not sure why...

It seems to me that I'm only going to have one Div that is left column, and one Div that is right column... so why would I use a class instead of an ID for this?

Comment: Elements with IDs are faster to access because they can be indexed. When that is said, it is always important to think of reusability, and IDs need to be unique. So whatever style you apply to an ID cannot be reused by another element

Comment: @NULL Specificity matters, though this question should be closed as *Primarily Opinion Based*

Comment: What does the CSS look like?

Comment: Here is the different - id's are unique. you can not use same id multiple time in the same page. but if you are creating a class, then you can apply that class in multiple time.

Comment: You may only have one left and right column, but would you never want to classify anything else as `left` or `right`?

Comment: @SalmanA there is no CSS, it's an exercise designed to teach good CSS writing practice. which is why I was confused that with an element that is almost certainly going to be used only once per page they asked us to use classes instead of id's. but Mateusz's answer below seems logical

Comment: I also add that some AJAX enabled websites/frameworks work by loading pages via AJAX inside a main page, creating duplicate ids.

Comment: You shouldn't be using "left column" and "right column" classes *or*  ids. Your class and id names should describe your content, not how you want it presented. Then use CSS selectors to bind your semantics to the CSS declarations that apply the left and right positions.

Comment: @Alohci. thanks. that seems logical. I don't understand the second sentence though.. would you mind rewording it? I'm not sure I know how you would do that..

Comment: Maybe an example might help. Let's say you have two articles on which you want to present together on your web page. One is about cats in general. The other is about your cat. So you put one in an element `<article class="cats">` the other in an element `<article class="mycat">`. If you get a second cat, and you add another article for that, you can use the same "mycat" class. Notice how you've said nothing in the HTML about how these articles are to be presented. Then by using applying CSS to `.cats` and `.mycats` you can place the articles into two columns.

Comment: ok thanks. in this case the left-column and right-column were the two pieces of content but I see how that is confusing.

Comment: @Mr.Alien thats why i voted to close this question, but no reason to not help OP just a little bit. To be fair this information would require at least 2 google searches. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably want you to refer to the element in order to move it somehow to left. It is better to use a class because it is possible that at some point you'll want to move another element to left. If you use id instead of class there may be need to repeat the same CSS rule for two different elements (different IDs). Code repetition is considered a bad practice and should be avoided, if possible at design level (no need to rewrite anything later), hence the suggestion to use class instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

IDs always perform well because they are unique per page, but somehow Code Academy could have the same ID. They might also want to avoid using IDs because of the dynamic application and structure, so we cannot predict how their skeleton is. I think it is as per their application logic.